# How to use form field value in twig template?

Tags: symfony

i have a formular and in there I have a collection of entities. In my template i would like to use this:

```
{% for service in form.services %}
    {{ form_label(service) }}
    {{ form_errors(service) }}
    {{ form_widget(service, {'attr': {'class': service.name}}) }}
{% endfor %}
```

Is it posiible to fetch a field name from the collection like in my example the field name?

With this i got an error.

Thanks Stefan

Comment: It goes something like {{ service.vars.value }}. Not quite sure now, you can see what 'service' field contains by using {{ dump(service) }} .

Comment: Hi , thanks for replay. This was helpfull, but in my case i need explcite a field from my entity. In form.servives are many entites. By a loop i need to set the class attr to the value of a property from the entity. In My case the field name. This dont work with your solution right now. And how can i setup debugging? I dont use this feature solong. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the debug toolbar, click on the form icon. There you can see what your form variable contains. `services` is probably an array of subforms. You can access a specific subform and then get the value of the "name" property like this: `services[0].name.vars.value` or you can of course loop through the whole array.

Comment: Thanks for reply but i think theres a mistake. i dont mean the name attribut from the input field, i have in my entity a property name too. This field i need to use as class. Not the input attribut name.

Comment: Yes, that's right. The `services` array holds the forms for your entities. The variable `name` holds the form field for the property "name" of the entity. From there you can access the current value of that property by calling `vars.value`.